# Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Don't really know why it is saying this but this is the code I believe it is talking about

```js
setUpdate(text, key) {
  const items = this.state.items;
  items.map((item) => {
    if (item.key === key) {
      item.text = text;
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    items: items,
  });
}
```

Comment: `.map` is for building an array from an existing, not for looping over an array. (Use `.forEach` for that.

Comment: Even better, in this case use `find` to get the element you want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use like below

```
setUpdate(text, key) {
  // loop the existing state and find the key value
  const nextItem = this.state.items.map((item) => {
    if (item.key === key) {
      item.text = text;
    }
    // return the modified item
    return item;
  });
  // set the new object into state
  this.setState({items: nextItem });
}
```

Comment: `items` is an array of objects with `key` and `text` properties, so I can't see how this could possibly work?

Comment: @bergi modified

Comment: Please don't follow this solution completely, it mutates the state object when doing `item.text = text;`. You need to also shallow copy nested state that is being updated. When updating arrays you should also use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state since the new array *depends* on the previous array. `{ ...nextItem }` will also fail since `nextItem` is an array, not an object.

Comment: @Drew Reese the second level update in object won't gives any error. map yields the new object so you won't get object mutation error

Comment: Please don't use `map` to iterate over an array, that is not what `map` is for. If the `if` matches on the first element then it will still iterate pointlessly over the entire array.

Comment: The map only copies the array, all the elements contained within are still references to objects in the previous state, thus `item.key === key` is in fact a state mutation. It doesn't matter if you shallow copy the array first, your solution mutates the previous state object.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

The `Array.prototype.map` function maps a one-to-one relationship, the resultant array will be the same length as the original. The error is saying that you aren't explicitly returning a value for each element iterated.

You also don't save the resultant mapped array. The result of your code is iteration over the `items` array and mutation with `item.text = text;`. In React state and props are to be considered immutable, mutating them directly is very anti-pattern.

```
setUpdate(text, key){
  const items = this.state.items; // <-- saved state reference
  items.map(item=>{ // <-- missing result array save
    if(item.key===key){
      item.text= text; // <-- state mutation!
    }
    // <-- missing return value (the error)
  })
  this.setState({
    items: items // <-- same reference to previous state!
  })
}
```

## Solution

You will want to shallow copy the array as well as any nested object that are being updated. Use a functional state update to correctly create the next state array from the state array from the previous state. The reason for this is that the next version of the `items` *necessarily* depends on the previous array.

```
setUpdate(text, key) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    items: prevState.items.map((item) =>
      item.key === key ? { ...item, key: text } : item
    )
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wrote this answer without realising that React requires you to provide a new array.**

You shouldn't be using `map` just to find and update an item in an array! What's wrong with `find`?

`find` will stop on the first element that matches the condition.

```js
setUpdate(text, key){
  const items = this.state.items;

  const item = items.find(i => i.key === key);

  if (item) item.text = text;

  this.setState({
    items: items
  });
}
```

Comment: Array.find, sure.... but what about React needing a new array reference so reconciliation and rerendering works with the new value?

Comment: Hadn't noticed the ReactJS tag - never used it, in which case this may not be an appropriate answer. Is React the reason why people over use `map` for iterating over an array?

Comment: We don't use `map` to simply iterate over the array, it's used to iterate, update an element, ***and*** return a new array reference. React uses shallow object equality to help determine what needs to be rerendered to the DOM. The the object reference is the same as previous render then it's assumed the value didn't change. This is why mutations are such a big deal and anti-pattern in React.

Comment: I get that, I just see a lot on non-React examples where a simple `foreach` or `for` would be better suited.

Comment: Oh, I see... I usually chock that up to devs just not simply understanding the fundamental differences between `map`, `forEach`, `reduce`, and other various ways to iterate javascript arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that add  a `return` keywork inside of map arrow function not just any HTML or compnent
Eg `

> 

```
  {props.meetups.map((meetup) => {
    return (
      <MeetupItem
        key={meetup.id}
        id={meetup.id}
        image={meetup.image}
        title={meetup.title}
        address={meetup.address}
        description={meetup.description}
      />
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this `Array.prototype.map()` issue by implementing what is written in [Eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/array-callback-return). Array mapping requires a return value.

> Array has several methods for filtering, mapping, and folding. If we
> forget to write return statement in a callback of those, it’s probably
> a mistake. If you don’t want to use a return or don’t need the
> returned results, consider using `.forEach` instead.